# PHP regular expression to replace new line with equal operator

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace a string from equal operator followed by newline to space.

```
From String:-
 Dr/CR,Entry Amount,Value date,Product,Party Code,Party Name,Virtual=\nAccount Number,Locations,RemittingBank,UTR No\nC,500000.0000,30-Mar-15,ABC,XYZ,QWER =\nLTD,LKJH,

To String:- 
 Dr/CR,Entry Amount,Value date,Product,Party Code,Party Name,Virtual Account   Number,Locations,RemittingBank,UTR No\nC,500000.0000,30-Mar-15,ABC,XYZ,QWER  LTD,LKJH,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use preg_replace.

```
preg_replace('~=\n~', " ", $str);
```

Comment: thanks @Avinash for quick response and save my time.